# Lookup parameters not always populating

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I have a standard lookup field that sometimes does not bring back results.

When the lookup *does* work, the Query String Parameters includes an id:

```
dplp: [null, "0012a0000068ndL"]
```

When the lookup does not work, the Query String Parameters only includes:

```
dplp: [null]
```

It appears that the dplp parameter is included in the URL on the lookup popup window:

Working:

https://kaesnavigator--part2sbx--c.cs47.visual.force.com/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=j_id0%3Aj_id8&lknm=j_id0%3Aj_id8%3AthePageBlock%3AcontractLine%3Aj_id176%3Aj_id178%3AshipFrom&lkfield=00N70000003GU4N&lkent=00k&lktp=a0P&**dplp=%5Bnull%2C%220012a0000068ndL%22%5D**&lksrch=

Not working:

https://org.visual.force.com/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=j_id0%3Aj_id8&lknm=j_id0%3Aj_id8%3AthePageBlock%3AcontractLine%3Aj_id176%3Aj_id178%3AshipFrom&lkfield=00N70000003GU4N&lkent=00k&lktp=a0P&**dplp=%5Bnull%5D**&lksrch=

Lookup field:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:outputLabel value="Ship From" for="shipFrom" />
  <apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputField value="{!newLine.Ship_From__c}" id="shipFrom" required="true">
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="shipTo" action="{!defaultAnotherField}" />
    </apex:inputField>
  </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The ids are Account ids. Account is used as a lookup filter, but removing the filter when the id is *not* populated in the parameters does not help the lookup window produce results.

Any thoughts on how to remedy this inconsistent behavior are GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: I'm guessing the ID is required because a look-up filter is based on the record's fields and if no id is provided, the look-up dialog box doesn't know what to match against. Removing the filter completely still wont work because there is no record to base it off of. Is it possible that newLine is null OR a new record that hasn't been inserted yet and thus, does not have an id?

Comment: @gNerb Thank you for your thoughts!!
That is very helpful about why removing the filter does not help.
The account is assigned when newLine is initiated, so it is on the form as an OutputField where you can view the name and id.
Based on that I know that the account does have an id, and so I assume newLine is not null, but could it be some sort of race condition in the controller?

Comment: I don't know that enough information is provided for us to be able to help answer that specific question.

Comment: Basically, I guess my question is if we can find out where the page is pulling that id from? I can verify it is set in the controller, and the value appears on the page, so it must be pulling it from somewhere on the visual force page. I agree that there is not much information about this!

Comment: I mean, you have the ID in the few cases that it does work, so what are the first three characters of the ID? Use that key to determine what object the ID belongs to and that should point you to what object in your controller has the ID it needs.

Comment: Looks like 001 so account so I'm not sure that actually helps :P You might have to provide your controller code for me to help any further.

Comment: I added the the controller function that defaults the field we need as a parameter.